# profile.name = "System Adminstrator" in formula field is not working

Tags: formula-field

I am using profile.name = "System Adminstrator" in formula field to set the checkbox true but it's not working. I have tried $profile.name = "System Adminstrator" also but still same result. For profile name other then System Adminstrator it is working perfectly fine.
Please help me with this.

Thank you,
Prakhar

Comment: You have a typo in the profile name. You wrote **"System Adminstrator"** instead of **"System Administrator"**. You need to make sure that the profile name matches exactly with the one in your org.

Answer (score 5):

The approach of checking profile names for disabling validation or determining other conditional behaviour has never been a good choice, and becomes less and less appropriate as Salesforce moves forwards with permission sets, permission set groups and other metadata replacing facets of profiles.

The platform already provides a mechanism for such use cases, these being [Custom Permissions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custom_perms_overview.htm&type=5). These can already be assigned to users through permission sets, meaning these are future-proof, though can also be assigned via profiles if you have not yet started the migration to permission sets (something you really should be doing).

Reference to the custom permission in a formula is straight forward using the permission's API name and the correct prefix, like:

```
$Permission.My_Custom_Permission
```

Such a reference can be inserted using the formula editor through "insert field" then selecting "Permission" and selecting the custom permission from the options made available.

You can get a bit more information through [this knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386266&type=1).

Comment: Profiles not going away, just permissions on Profiles (allegedly, Spring 26) . That said, it would not be best practice to have to worry about which Profile to assign to a user and which Permission Set Group to assign to same user; Ideally orgs migrate to a common baseline Profile w/o permissions and then use PSGs to assign permissions.

Comment: @cropredy yeah, some folks on X have corrected me with the latest roadmap - will update the answer.