# Where is the official documentation for how the "$Permission" field type functions in Formula Fields?

Tags: formula-field, permissions

You can create Formula Fields that reference values from "$Permission". How are those values created? What is being referenced?

Providing the official documentation and additional functionality that is not mentioned in the docs would be appreciated.

Comment: Custom Permissions. Very easy to create. You add their (API) name after `$Permission.`. You can grant a user a custom permission via perm set or profile.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much official documentation, which is weird. Anyway, take a look [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/413599/profile-name-system-adminstrator-in-formula-field-is-not-working/413600#413600).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One place you can see the documentation for `$Permission` (and other Global variables) is in the [Visualforce Developer Guide $Permission page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_permission.htm)

> $Permission
>
> A global merge field type to use when referencing information about the current user’s custom permission access. Use permission merge fields to reference information about the user’s current access to any of your organization’s custom permissions.
>
> Usage
>
> Select the field type: $Permission.

> Select a merge field such as $Permission.customPermissionName.
>
> Example
>
> To have a pageblock only appear for users that have the custom permission seeExecutiveData, use the following.

```
<apex:pageBlock rendered="{!$Permission.canSeeExecutiveData}">
   <!-- Executive Data Here -->
</apex:pageBlock>
```